# Correct Arch Installation procedure

Tags: boot, archlinux, pi-3b+

What is the correct procedure to install Arch on raspberry pi 3 b+??

I've followed the instructions on this page: [Arch Wiki](https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv8/broadcom/raspberry-pi-3)

substituting ArchLinuxARM-rpi-2-latest.tar.gz with ArchLinuxARM-rpi-3-latest.tar.gz

but it won't boot.

I've noticed this on the wiki:

> **AArch64 Installation:**
>
> This provides an installation using the mainline kernel and U-Boot. Use this installation only if you have no dependencies on the closed source vendor libraries shipped in the ARMv7 release. This installation has near full support for the device, including the VC4 graphics.
>
> This installation does not yet support the Raspberry Pi 3B+.
>
> Follow the above instructions, substituting with the following tarball:
>
> http://os.archlinuxarm.org/os/ArchLinuxARM-rpi-3-latest.tar.gz

I'm not sure what does it mean(English is not my first language)

For diagnosis purpose:
I'm on Manjaro, already tried with raspbian and it works perfectly.

Comment: RPi3B+ isn't fully compatible with older RPI3B distros - perhaps, even after almost 5 months the Arch Linux people haven't figured that out yet

Comment: So I have to install other distros?

Comment: That would seem to be the case

Comment: Ok thanks, since I'm new to raspberry I ll stick to raspbian and hope for the future

Comment: you may want to read https://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=65&t=12661 - looks like there is support after all

Answer (score 1):

Two posts from this [thread](https://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=65&t=12661&sid=228c8d15f8e4d7e4cf20c2af4e04bf56&start=20) (posted end of August and early September 2018) claim to have Arch installed following the [official guide](https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv8/broadcom/raspberry-pi-3).

> I flashed the aarch64 system to my raspberry pi 3B+ by following the guides here, it worked quite well, except audio and gpu hardware acceleration (omxplayer is unavailable now). And also you'd better split more memory to gpu_mem (mine is 128) in /boot/config.txt or you might encounter nasty errors, slow boots and blank screen.

Furthermore the line

> This installation does not yet support the Raspberry Pi 3B+.

as posted in the question has been removed from the Arch Wiki.

Additionally this questions here [64bit distribution on compute module 3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/89894/19949) found that:

> [...] Arch linux have a 64 version of his distribution ( https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv8/broadcom/raspberry-pi-3 ). I've tried it in the raspberry pi 3 B+ without any problem [...]