# 64bit distribution on compute module 3

Tags: archlinux, compute-module-3, 64-bit

I'm trying to run a 64bit distribution on Raspberry compute module 3.

I've found that Arch linux have a 64 version of his distribution ( https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv8/broadcom/raspberry-pi-3 ).
I've tried it in the raspberry pi 3 B+ without any problem, but in the compute module 3, the boot hang because it can't find the bcm2837-rpi-cm3-io3.dts file.

I've also found a thread about this problem on Arch linux forum: https://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=12525

Do you know where I can find this file?
Do you know if there is a 64 bit distribution that I can run on compute module?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I notice that - as a byproduct of your research - you have made Arch work on the Pi 3+. There is another question about that which might profit from your insight if you care to provide another answer. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/87508/19949 Thanks.